# what is "evening series" referring to in this context?

Tags: vocabulary, american-english, learning

The Headline I came across is:

"Yankees keep season alive by evening series With Guardians"

what is the "evening series" refering to?

Comment: Can you link to the article.  Usually headlines are very clear when you look at the article, but here I'd guess "A series of games (of baseball) played in the evening".

Comment: Hey, turns out I was wrong, -- that's why you need to link to the article.

Answer (score 5):

TITLE: **Yankees keep season alive by evening series With Guardians.**

**To even means to make the score even**. The Yankees evened the score in the series when they played the Guardians.

The verb is a participle for purpose of writing a headline.

See the full article here:

[The Spokesman](https://www.spokesman.com/stories/2022/oct/16/yankees-keep-season-alive-by-evening-series-with-g/)

evening here is not referring to the night. It's the verb to even something.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be interpreting "evening" as a noun, but that is incorrect in this case. It is actually the gerund form of the verb "to even". [From M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/even):

> **even** verb
> **evened**; **evening** \ ˈēv-​niŋ  , ˈē-​və-​ \
> Definition of *even* (Entry 3 of 4)
> *transitive verb*
> : to make even

Comment: I don't see how this adds anything to the existing answer

Comment: @FumbleFingers I was on the fence about posting this for that very reason, but there are some differences: 1) This answer uses the term "gerund" whereas Lambie calls it a "participle", 2) I more explicitly identified the difference in form ("noun" vs. "gerund"), and 3) I provided the definition of the word in question. (For the record, I upvoted Lambie's answer, which I find to be a good one.)

Comment: Fair enough. I don't know how much good it does them, but many learners are endlessly preoccupied with things like the "noun" vs. "gerund" distinction. But like @James as commenting under the question, *absent context,* I took it for granted the meaning was *played in the evening*. (If I was editor of the publication in which it appeared, I'd probably sack the unthinking hack who wrote such a pointlessly confusing headline! :)